# How to create a multiline plot

Tags: r

I have the following question. I would like to create a line plot in R that differentiates by the variable 'Nr' but also differentiates between pattern 1 (solid line) and pattern 2 (dashed line) for each of the individual courses. The plot should look like this:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iDAU.png)

My code is:

```
sc = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)
pat = c("Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", 
       "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", 
       "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", 
       "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2",
       "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2",
       "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2")
nr= c(3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
changes = c(10,8,7,5,4,7,3,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,11,8,4,2,1,6,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0)

df <- data.frame(sc = sc, pat = pat, nr = nr, changes = changes)
```

How do I get this to work? My guess would be ggplot but i dont know how.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ggplot with geom_line using the conditional for both the colour and linetype. Here is the answer

```
sc = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4)
pat = c("Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", 
        "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", 
        "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", "Pattern 1", 
        "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2",
        "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2",
        "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2", "Pattern 2")
nr= c(3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
changes = c(10,8,7,5,4,7,3,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,11,8,4,2,1,6,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0)

df <- data.frame(sc = sc, pat = pat, nr = nr, changes = changes)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = sc, y = changes, color = as.factor(nr))) + 
  geom_line(mapping = aes(linetype = pat)) +
  labs(color = "nr", linetype = "pattern")
```

[image]